# No trace info during processing of a cube in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005, ssas, trace, olap

When I process a cube in Visual Studio 2005 I get following message:

> Process succeeded. Trace information
>   is still being transferred. If you do
>   not want to wait for all of the
>   information to arrive press Stop.

and no trace info is displayed. Cube is processed OK by it is a little bit annoying. Any ideas? I access cubes via web server.

Comment: So, what was the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same message when I process a cube, but if I wait for a few seconds the trace information arrives.  Are you dealing with a very large quantity of data or a very complex cube?  Maybe this is a silly question, but have you tried waiting a few minutes?

Comment: I have really small data. But I dont use local access. I used this datapump dll and HTTP access.

Answer (score 3):

I get the same message when processing through GUI. I've never encountered this before, even on Dev or at other companies. I can't find a workaround and there seems to be a reall issue here (connect issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/536543/ssas-process-progress-window-blank-no-details)

Any workarounds would be great...

Answer (score 0):

how are you processing the cube? through XMLA or through the GUI? If you do it in XMLA then you should see the results as they come in the output window